# How to check that every value in a hash-table satisfies a predicate in Common Lisp

Tags: common-lisp, hashtable

I have an hash table
`(setf ht (make-hash-table))`
which contains some entries, for example `(setf (gethash 'first ht) 'first-value)`, `(setf (gethash 'second ht) 'second-value)`, ...

Furthermore I have a predicate `test` of arity one that evaluate to `T` or `NIL`.  I want to check if all first entries of the hash table `ht` satisfy the `test` predicate.  If, for example, the hash table consists of only the two entries given above, I want to know the evaluation of `(and (test 'first) (test 'second))`.  Is there a simple way to do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'd like to know how you do what [every](http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/iiip/doc/CommonLISP/HyperSpec/Body/fun_everycm_s_erycm_notany.html) does with sequences, with hash tables.

You can use the [loop](http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/iiip/doc/CommonLISP/HyperSpec/Body/mac_loop.html) macro to iterate over every value and use `:always` to check each element for your test. As with `every` `:always` will terminate the loop immediately when the test is `NIL`.

```
(defun hash-every (test hash)
 (loop :for value :being :the :hash-values :in hash 
       :always (funcall test value)))

(hash-every #'numberp ht) ; ==> NIL
(hash-every #'symbolp ht) ; ==> T
```

You'd probably want to look the the [Common Lisp Cookbok's hash table page](http://cl-cookbook.sourceforge.net/hashes.html) for more hints.